# Use AJAX to display dictionary data returned by Django view in a table on the template

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, django

I saw some posts on this topic but none quite similar. I am getting back a dictionary in JSON format from a Django view as shown below:

```
# display game statistics on the developer homepage
def gamestats(request):

    countlist = []
    datedict = {}
    if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax:
        id = request.POST.get('id',None)
        gameobj = Games.objects.filter(pk=id)
        # get queryset of Scores objects with the selected game ID
        scores = Scores.objects.filter(game=gameobj)
        # get list of distinct registration dates from "scores" queryset
        datelist = scores.values_list('registration_date',flat=True).distinct()
        for dateobj in datelist:
            scoredate = scores.filter(registration_date=dateobj)
            c = scoredate.count()
            countlist.append(c)

        n = len(countlist)
        for i in range(n):
            t = datelist[i].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            datedict[t] = countlist[i]
            print(t)
            print(datedict[t])

        json_stats = json.dumps(datedict)
        return HttpResponse(json_stats,content_type='application/json')
```

This dictionary holds data in the form:

```
{ "29/01/2015" : 2, "21/12/2014" : 1, "23/01/2015": 3 }
```

Now, on the client side, the AJAX code is given below:

```
$(".stats").click(function(){
    var game = $(this);
    var id = game.attr('id');
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/gamestats/",
        data : {'id': id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken},
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
            //var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
            //for (var key in obj){
            //    alert("inside for loop");
            //    var value = obj[key];
            //    alert(value);
            //    $("#gamestats").html(value);
            //}
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

The relevant HTML code:
    ...

```
<tr>
    <td width="10%" align="center"><button class="stats" id="{{game.id}}"> View game statistics</button></td>
</tr>

...

<b>Game statistics: </b>
<p id="gamestats"></p>
```

Due to my very limited knowledge of AJAX, I do not know how to handle the response inside the "success" parameter of the request. I want to display the JSON data in a table, with 2 columns, one for the dates (keys) and other for the corresponding numbers (values). I want to do this inside the "gamestats" section of the page. I tried some things but they don't display anything. Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take a JSON object and put it into a table you can loop over it like so:

```
var tableData = '<table>'
$.each(data, function(key, value){
        tableData += '<tr>';
        tableData += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
        tableData += '</tr>';
});
tableData += '</table>';

$('#table').html(tableData);
```

Comment: I think there are some syntax problems in the code. Instead of "var tableData += '<table>'" shouldn't it be "var tableData = '<table>'", because initially there are no values assigned to tableData?

Comment: @user3033194 Good catch. I was doing this quickly. I'll edit.

Comment: The table is still not showing. When I am writing alert(data) for debugging, a box opens displaying [object Object]. However, when I write alert(data) after the line "obj = $.parseJSON(data)", nothing shows. The same happens when I am writing alert(obj). If the dataType is given as 'json', shouldn't the parsing be done automatically?

Comment: @aus_lucy OK, it works now. That line "obj = $.parseJSON(data)" is not needed, as "data" is already in JSON format. So I replaced "$.each(obj, function(key, value){" with "$.each(data, function(key, value){". Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user3033194 ahh yes I forgot that Django `json.dumps` takes care of that for you. I edited my answer. Glad to help. Don't forget to up-vote/accept as the answer for future SO users can easily locate solutions to their similar problems.